# Android studio not downloading completely

Tags: android, installation

I am new to Android Studio and downloaded it last day on my mac, but I could never use it.  The components download almost reaches its end and then this error keep coming up.  Please help.  I really want to do my project.

> Warning: An error occurred during installation: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r30.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK

This above warning keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my Android Studio 3.1.2.
It was solved by changing HTTP proxy settings to use system configured.

Go to Settings -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> Auto-detect proxy settings.

Answer (score -3):

Open the downloaded DMG file

Android Studio put in the directory Applications

According to the applied security setting , warnings that say the package is endommangé when any of the Android Studio is opened appears.

To fix this : Go to " System Preferences > Security & Privacy" and under "Allow applications downloaded from " choose anywhere.

Comment: Please, avoid answers in different languages